# How to get the last date from 2 dates in select statement

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create select statement in procedure.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT u.id, max(a.time), max(b.time)
FROM buy a, sell b, users u
WHERE a.user_id = u.id AND b.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

I need to take the last date between `max(a.time)` and `max(b.time)`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use CASE for a.time and b.time.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT u.id, max(case when a.time > b.time then a.time else b.time end)
FROM buy a, sell b, users u
WHERE a.user_id = u.id AND b.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

If your DB supports aliased queries, try this which would be much more efficient:

```
SELECT u.id, case when a_max > b_max then a_max else b_max end
FROM (SELECT u.id, max(a.time) as a_max, max(b.time) as b_max
    FROM buy a, sell b, users u
    WHERE a.user_id = u.id AND b.user_id = u.id
    GROUP BY u.id) x;
```

The inner query could use indexes if they existed to get the max for each column quickly.

---

While we're at it, let's re-code it using the modern join syntax:

```
SELECT u.id, max(case when a.time > b.time then a.time else b.time end)
FROM buy a
JOIN sell b ON b.user_id = u.id
JOIN users u ON a.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

Comment: Is that really a good idea?  Surely one should aggregate then wrap CASE around the aggregates?  This would allow the optimiser more opportunity to reduce the workload.

Comment: I don't know if sql-developer supports aliased queries, but if it did - see edited answer

Comment: There is a way to optimize this query?

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
SELECT 
  u.id, 
  CASE 
    WHEN max(a.time) > max(b.time) THEN max(a.time)
    ELSE max(b.time)
  END
FROM buy a, sell b, users u
WHERE a.user_id = u.id AND b.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

Comment: Note that this will would calculate four max() functions

Comment: Change `CASE` to `CASE WHEN`?

Comment: @Bohemian - Not to my knowledge.  It would calculate `MAX(a.time)` once and use the result twice.

Comment: You are missing WHEN after CASE

Comment: also `Case` statement need to `END`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT U.ID, 
CASE WHEN MAX(A.TIME) > MAX(B.TIME) THEN MAX(A.TIME)
     ELSE MAX(B.TIME) 
END
FROM BUY A, SELL B, USERS U
WHERE A.USER_ID = U.ID AND B.USER_ID = U.ID
GROUP BY U.ID;
```